# Proof Verification: Using Taylor series to arrive at a certain inequality

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, inequality, taylor-expansion

If $x>0$ show that $|(1+x)^{1/3} - (1 + \frac{1}{3}x - \frac{1}{9}x^2)| \le \frac{5}{81}x^3$.

Proof:

Let $f(x) = (1 +x)^{1/3}$

Then, estimating $f(x)$ at the point $x_o = 0$, we have that:

$f'(x) = 1/3(1+x)^{-2/3}, f"(x) = -2/9(1+x)^{-5/3}, f^{(3)}(x)= 10/27 (1+x)^{-8/3}$

Then,

$P_{3} = 1 + \frac{1}{3}x - \frac{1}{9}x^2 + \frac{5}{81}x^3$

And we have that:

$R_3 = \frac{-10}{243} (1+c)^{-11/3}x^4 <0$ for $c \in (0,x)$

Then this implies that:

$(1+x)^{1/3} < 1+ \frac{1}{3}x -\frac{1}{9}x^2 +\frac{5}{81}x^3$

$\implies (1+x)^{1/3}- (1+ \frac{1}{3}x -\frac{1}{9}x^2 ) <\frac{5}{81}x^3$

**I don't understand how to transform the above expression into the one that we're required to show. Can anyone explain why it should be $\le$ instead of $<$. Also, how and why do we need the absolute signs?**

Please help. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think you are right and that you proved something stronger that what was asked, but I'll let another person give you a formal answer :-P

Comment: Can you please help if you have time? Regardless, thank you for the comment, I'm assuming I haven't done anything wrong?

Comment: I don't know why the exponent in $R_3$ is $-\frac{11}{3}$ and not $-\frac{8}{3}$, can you clarify it?

Comment: I spot an error; my first comment was wrong. I'll write an answer in a few moments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got $(1+x)^{1/3}- (1+ \frac{1}{3}x -\frac{1}{9}x^2 ) <\frac{5}{81}x^3$, but the value on the left side could be a very big negative number, so you **actually** have to show that the absolute value is smaller than $\frac{5}{81} x^3$.

Working with $P_3, R_3$ is "too much". I suggest to get $P_2,R_2$. Doing that you will get $\leq$ instead of $<$. Feel free to ask me if you don't understand.

Comment: So, $R_{2}=\frac{5}{81}(1+c)^{-8/3}x^3>0$ Then, $R_{2}=\frac{5}{81}(1+c)^{-8/3}x^3<\frac{5}{81}x^3$ And then, we can get to the inequality. But again,wouldn't it be strict inequality without the absolute signs?

Comment: Because for any $ c \in (0,x)$, $0<(1+c)^{-8/3}<1$

Comment: Let me see...you have $f= P_2 + R_2 \Rightarrow f-P_2 = R_2 \Rightarrow |f-P_2| = |R_2|$. As you say, $R_2 < \frac{5}{81}x^3$, but also it is positive, so it is equal to its absolute value. Then, $|f-P_2| < \frac{5}{81} x^3$. I think you are right, you can actually prove $<$

Comment: In fact, I plugged the formula in wolfram alpha and the equality only holds at $x=0$, so the strict inequality is true. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Bx)%5E%7B1%2F3%7D-(1%2B1%2F3+x+-1%2F9+x%5E2)+-+5%2F81+x%5E3

Comment: Thank you so much! That helps a lot! :D